# EntityFrameworkCore DbSet.Where

Tags: lambda, entity-framework-core, dbset

I want to filter my DbSet by multiple `Lambda` expressions.
Here is the implementation.
1.Expression

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }


public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
    (Expression.And(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
}
```

2. Implementation COde

```
public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetMany(Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>> where, int page, int pageSize, out int totalCount)
{
    totalCount = _userRepository.DbSet.Where(where).Count();
    var devices = _userRepository.DbSet.Where(where).Include(p => p.Group)
        .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).AsEnumerable();
    return devices;
}
```

3.Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll([FromQuery] string name = "",int groupId=0, int page = 1, int pageSize = 20)
{
    int groupid = await GetCurrentLoginUserGroupID();
    List<int> _groupIdList = _groupSvc.GetGroupTreeID(groupid);
    IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> users = null;
    int totalCount = 0;
    if (pageSize >= ConstConfig.MaxItemSizePerPage)
    {
        pageSize = ConstConfig.MaxItemSizePerPage;
    }
    else if (pageSize < 1)
    {
        pageSize = 1;
    }            
    var where = PredicateBuilder.True<ApplicationUser>().And(g => _groupIdList.Contains(g.GroupId.GetValueOrDefault()));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        where.And(n => n.UserName.Contains(name));
    }
    if (groupId > 0)
    {
        where.And(g => g.GroupId == groupId);
    }
    users = _userService.GetMany(where,page,pageSize, out totalCount);
```

I have check the value for name, but the return value for `users` did not meet this filter.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a real question, please provide more details about what do you want to do in order we can provide a better help

Comment: I want to filter my user records by `_userRepository.DbSet.Where` and `n => n.UserName.Contains(name)` and `g => g.GroupId == groupId` but the current code did not work. It did not apply the filter

Comment: You are not using predicate builder methods correctly (basically igoring them). In all places it should be `where = where.And(...)`. Also note that the predicate builder you are using will cause client evaluation (in cause you are not using the full LINQKit and `AsExpandable`).

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks a lot, your suggestion works, it's my mistake. Could you share me more detail information about `will cause client evaluation ` and `full LINQKit and AsExpandable`?

Comment: Disregard that part - it was an issue with EF6 which seems to be fixed in EF Core. Just replace `Expression.And` with `Expression.AndAlso` to get better SQL translation :) Cheers.